# How do I combine two hex files created by Keil uVision?

Tags: arm, bootloader, keil

I am using the Keil uVision4 IDE to program an NXP LPC1768.  I need recommendations for combining two hex files.  The two files are going to be a boot loader and an application that will be used for production programming.  Currently, I am successfully able to program each file to the device independently.  This is done by running a build on each project and loading via the Keil uVision4 IDE.

Also, is it a valid approach to program the microcontroller with just the boot loader and then use the boot loader to upload the application file?

In regards to effort - I currently have each file built from the IDE.  Following each build a hex file is automatically created and then downloaded to the device by using the `FLASH->DOWNLOAD` option in the IDE.  Using the specfic "options for target" within the IDE, I can successfully load the boot at memory address `0x0` and the application at `0x10000`.

Comment: Can you show your effort?

Comment: Define what you mean by "hex file"

Comment: Re hex file: Keil target options output tab - create hex file is checked

Comment: Re effort: Each application build is defined in Keil options for target, so following each build there is a hex file created.  The hex file is loaded from the IDE with the FLASH->DOWNLOAD.  Each application load correctly this way, with boot loader loaded at 0x0 and user app loaded at 0x10000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an application called Hexmate to do this.  I think it was created by Microchip a while ago, but you can certainly use it with hex files for other micros.  You can find it here: http://www.schmalzhaus.com/Tools/HexmateInstructions.html

The manual is part of the PICC18 manual which can be found here (look at section 5.15):
http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/manual_STD952.pdf

The command to merge two files, one called "bootload.hex" and one called "mainline.hex" and output them to a file called "merged.hex" is:

```
hexmate bootload.hex mainline.hex -omerged.hex
```

Make sure that all 3 files are in the same directory when you execute that line.

Answer (score 3):

[SRECORD](http://srecord.sourceforge.net) can finish this task too.

```
srec_cat.exe Bootloader.hex -Intel Application.hex -Intel -out Combinded.hex -Intel
```